# Bizarre Proguard Error in Android, toString() called but call doesn't exist?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I'm trying to get proguard working with my android app. With `minifyEnabled` set to false, the app runs fine. When **true**, I get the following error:

```
04-09 22:39:21.622 21657-21657/com.jcg.grocerylistconverter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jcg.grocerylistconverter, PID: 21657
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jcg.grocerylistconverter/com.jcg.grocerylistconverter.RecipeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.AbstractMap.toString()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.AbstractMap.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.jcg.grocerylistconverter.p.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6929)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Now if I look in my RecipeActivity, there is no method call AT ALL to `toString()`:

```
public class RecipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "RecipeActivity";

private RecipeDatabase dbHelper;

private String mMenuRecipeTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_RA);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    String retreivedRecipe = getIntent().getStringExtra("recipeKey");
    String retrievedGson = getIntent().getStringExtra("gsonRecipe");

    dbHelper = RecipeDatabase.getInstance(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            "rowid AS " + RecipeContract.Columns._ID,
            RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_NAME,
            RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_CUPSTOGRAMS,
            RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_SORTLIST,
            RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_MEALTYPE
    };
    String whereclause = RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_NAME + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[] {retreivedRecipe};


    Cursor cursor = db.query(RecipeContract.TABLE_NAME, columns, whereclause, whereargs,
            null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String listName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_SORTLIST));
    mMenuRecipeTitle = listName;
    cursor.close();


    RecipeActivityFragment fragment = new RecipeActivityFragment();

    if (retreivedRecipe != null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("retrievedRecipe", retreivedRecipe);
        bundle.putString("retrievedGson", retrievedGson);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_recipe_activity, fragment, TAG).commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipe_activity, menu);
    MenuItem recipeListName = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_RecipeList);
    recipeListName.setTitle(mMenuRecipeTitle);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I'll post my dependencies in my `build.gradle` file and my `proguard-rules.pro` below.

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

}

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class google.code.gson.** { *; }

-keep class com.fasterxml.databind.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.annotations.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.core.** { *; }

-keep class com.jaredrumler.material-spinner.** { *; }

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** {*;}
-keepnames interface com.fasterxml.jackson.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.annotations.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.core.**

-dontwarn com.jaredrumler.material-spinner.**

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** e(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** wtf(...);
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
```

Really confused about what's going on here, I've extensively searched up similar issues to this problem but I can't find anything. Do I need to place a `-dontwarn` call to `AbstractMap`? It seems a bit extreme.

EDIT: this is my RecipeActivityFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_activity, container, false);
    mRecipeTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipeactivityfragment_name);
    mMealType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipeactivityfragment_meal);
    mIngredientTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rfa_ingredients);
    mGramTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rfa_grams);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipe_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(0));

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    final String recipeName = arguments.getString("retrievedRecipe");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: recipeName = " + recipeName);

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            "rowid AS " + RecipeContract.Columns._ID,
                    RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_NAME,
            RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_CUPSTOGRAMS,
            RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_SORTLIST,
            RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_MEALTYPE
    };
    String whereclause = RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_NAME + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[] {recipeName};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(RecipeContract.TABLE_NAME, columns, whereclause, whereargs,
            null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String recipeTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_NAME));
    String recipeCupsToGrams = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_CUPSTOGRAMS));
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: cupsToGrams = " + recipeCupsToGrams);
    // other cups etc here
    String recipeMealType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_MEALTYPE));
    String listName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RecipeContract.Columns.RECIPE_SORTLIST));
    mMenuRecipeTitle = listName;
    cursor.close();


    final String recipeGson = arguments.getString("retrievedGson");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: recipeGson = " + recipeGson);
    Recipe r;
    r = mGson.fromJson(recipeGson, Recipe.class);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: hashMapToString... = " + hashMapToJSONtoHashMap(r).toString());

    mRecipeTitle.setText(recipeTitle);
    mMealType.setText(recipeMealType);

    JSONtoHashMap(recipeCupsToGrams);
    mIngredientAdapter = new IngredientAdapter(JSONtoHashMap(recipeCupsToGrams));

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mIngredientAdapter);

    return view;
}


private HashMap<String, Float> hashMapToJSONtoHashMap(Recipe r) {
    String json = mGson.toJson(r.getIngredientsGrams());
    HashMap<String, Float> noWork = new HashMap<>();

    HashMap<String, Float> cupsToGrams;
    try {
        cupsToGrams = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return noWork;
    }
    return cupsToGrams;

}
```

As soon as I remove the call to the line

`Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: hashMapToString... = " + hashMapToJSONtoHashMap(r).toString());`

It runs fine. Why does this work fine with proguard off?

Comment: put breakpoints and see the values of the variables.

Comment: `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_recipe_activity, fragment, TAG).commit();` `replace` should have been `add`

Comment: also the error is in fragment `RecipeActivityFragment.onCreateView`, can you post its code?

Comment: @RahulKumar thanks for your reply. Why is replace worse than add?